# How SendLog can capture sent event date?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, data-views

I am looking into the current SentLog and not seeing any date like Send date. How can I get / capture sent event date in send log?

Answer (score 2):

Add a new field of the date type, set it to be nullable and then configure it to use the current system date as the default value. This way when a new row is inserted, it will get the date value automatically.

Comment: Hi Rafal, thank you for your response. Yes, that is my plan (as a workaround solution) but I was just surprised that there is no send event date out of the box in Send Log. So I wanted to confirm if I am missing anything or there is a process to get send event date?

Comment: Surprisingly, it's not there in the SendLog template we're using for it's creation, so it's really up to you to add it in whatever way you want. I would recommend checking how you can improve the send log as desribed by Mateusz Dabrowski here: https://mateuszdabrowski.pl/docs/usecase/sfmc-enhanced-send-log/